# What's the value of the segment $AE$ in the quadrilateral circumscribed in the question below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference (exact copy of the question):

> In the $ABCD$ quadrilateral circumscribed to a circle, $AB$ and $CD$ are tangents at $T$ and $Q$ respectively, $TQ$ intercepts $AC$ at $E$.
> $EC = 10$, $QC = 8$ and $AT = 4$.
>
> Calculate $AE$.

---

My progress:

It follows the resolution by trigonometry... could anyone solve it by geometry?

[image]

$\angle EQC=\alpha$

$OQ$ is ratio, therefore $OQ \perp QC \Rightarrow \theta +\alpha=90^\circ$.

$\triangle OQT$ isosceles, therefore $\angle OQT=\angle OTQ$, therefore $\angle QTB=\alpha$.

Law of sines:

- $\triangle ATE$:

$$
\tag{$I$}
\frac{AT}{\sin \beta}
=\frac{AE}{{\underbrace{\sin (\pi−\alpha)}}_{\sin\alpha}}\ .
$$

- $\triangle ECQ$:

$$
\tag{$II$}
\frac{QC}{\sin\beta}=\frac{CE}{\sin\alpha}
\ .
$$

$(II) \div (I)$ gives:
$$\frac{AT}{QC}=\frac{AE}{CE}
\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad
\frac{4}{8}=\frac{AE}{10}\ ,
$$
and therefore $AE=5$.

Comment: Can you explain "tangents at A and B at T and Q respectively", and how that aligns with your diagram?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please **separate** in the future the text from the formulas, please type the text, the sentences as text, not artificially inside the dollars. To see the difference, between dollars, `$difference$` gives $difference$, the product of letters. The "ligature" ff is gone. Please take a look at the edited version, it may be useful in the future. Note that among the many translations of resolución in https://dict.leo.org/spanish-english/resoluci%C3%B3n the one matching best is maybe "solution", resolution is rather decisión or decreto (both languages not my languages)...

Comment: @CalvinLin..tangency point T on AB and tangency point Q on CD

Comment: @dan_fulea..understood, I'll do as I say in the next questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points $B,D$ are not needed, so let us remove them from the picture. Now the circle plays only the rôle of making the two angles in $T,Q$, marked in the posted picture by the same letter $\alpha$ to have the same measure.
So let us isolate the essence, the problem is reduced to the following one:

[image]

> The points $A,C;T,Q;E$ are given such that $AC\cap TQ=E$, and we know the angle relations:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \beta &=\widehat{AET} =\widehat{CEQ}\ ,\\
> \alpha &=\widehat{EQC} \ ,\\
> 180^\circ-\alpha &=\widehat{ATE} \ .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> The problem is not to determine a (proportionality) relation between $AT,AE$ and $CQ,CE$.

As shown in the picture, let $T^*$ be on $QE$ such that $\Delta ATT^*$ is isosceles (in $A$). (For this construct $T^*$ as the reflection of $T$ w.r.t. the perpendicular line on $QET$ which is passing through $A$.)

It is now easy to see the similarity:
$$
\Delta AT^*E\sim \Delta CQE\ ,
$$
(corresponding two angles of measure $\alpha,\beta$), so we get:
$$
\frac {AT}{AE} =
\frac {AT^*}{AE} =
\frac {CQ}{CE}
\ .
$$
$\square$